# How do I use hitTest:withEvent: to send touches from my nav bar to the underlying view under certain circumstances?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Long story short, if the `alpha` of my UINavigationBar is set to 0, I want all touches to go to the underlying view (which from the perspective of the view controller with the navigation bar would just be `self.view`). If it's `1.0`, I want it to keep them.

I subclassed UINavigationBar, and I'm trying to override `hitTest:withEvent:`, but I'm really confused what I'm doing, and searching has been of little help.

How do I tell it, "if alpha is 0, send touch to `self.view`, otherwise keep on navigation bar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to send a reference of your view into the navigation bar, set it as a property called `behindView` or something.

```
if(self.alpha == 0.0f)
{
    return behindView;
}
return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
```

Another way would be to override `pointInside:withEvent:` like this:

```
if(self.alpha == 0.0f)
{
    return NO;
}
return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
```

Comment: It doesn't get called if I tap the navigation bar when its alpha is set to 0.

Comment: That makes sense actually. Are you sure your view's frame has been expanded up behind where the invisible navigation bar is? The navigation controller will set your view controller's view-top below the navigation bar, so you may need to put all your content into an inner-view that has a `frame.origin.y` of `-navBarHeight` and that view will get your touches.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** version.

**Code:**

```
class NavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        if self.alpha == 0 {
            return false
        }
        return super.point(inside: point, with: event)
    }

}
```